# MongoDB Server not starting - Mac OS Ventura

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, homebrew, macos-ventura

I am on a M1 MacBook Air running Mac OS Ventura. I have a fresh install of home-brew and MongoDB Community@6.0. But when I tried the command

> mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf --fork

I am getting the error

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 9724
ERROR: child process failed, exited with 14
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
```

I used to work with the MongoDB without any issue, I guess this came after the Ventura update. I tried reinstalling both home-brew and mongoDB.

mongo.log

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.457+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.463+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.465+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.466+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.466+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.466+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.466+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":9001,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Sravans-MacBook-Air.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23352,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unable to resolve sysctl {sysctlName} (number) ","attr":{"sysctlName":"hw.cpufrequency"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.features"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.1","gitVersion":"32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"aarch64","target_arch":"aarch64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"22.1.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.467+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.467+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1120}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:34:51.467+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.486+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.486+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.488+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.491+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.492+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.493+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.493+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.493+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.493+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":9724,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Sravans-MacBook-Air.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.494+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23352,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unable to resolve sysctl {sysctlName} (number) ","attr":{"sysctlName":"hw.cpufrequency"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.494+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.features"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.494+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.1","gitVersion":"32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"aarch64","target_arch":"aarch64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.495+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"22.1.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.495+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"processManagement":{"fork":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.495+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.495+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1120}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:36:33.496+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}

{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.160+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.164+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.164+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.169+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.170+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":9909,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Sravans-MacBook-Air.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23352,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unable to resolve sysctl {sysctlName} (number) ","attr":{"sysctlName":"hw.cpufrequency"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.features"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.1","gitVersion":"32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"aarch64","target_arch":"aarch64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"22.1.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/opt/homebrew/var/mongodb"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1120}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-31T20:42:03.171+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

Comment: you should provide full log

Comment: `ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}`

Comment: @dododo I am just getting comfortable with MongoDB. How will I rectify this?

Comment: look at https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongod-failed-to-unlink-socket-file-tmp-mongodb-27017/150362/5

Comment: @dododo thank you for reaching out , appreciate it.